# Web scraping for product details, not a list / table in UIPath

Tags: web-scraping, uipath

I have situation where I want to scrape a profile of a company for example with 20 / 30 different attributes layout on one page, save each of those elements as a column title, and paginate through a directory and build a table with each page as a row, and the columns being the various data points (that all have different tags on the same page, but are consistent across different pages)

Right now I have been going through laborious process of copying text and using UI explorer to find an element, which is a real pain compared to the screen scraping wizard.

below is a link to a profile on test for example, the tags on the page are all different, but if I want to scrape another page, the tags will be the same, so can paginate through and create a really valuable table of all these companies.

https://www.owler.com/company/tesla

Ref : https://forum.uipath.com/t/web-scraping-for-details-not-a-list-table/68802

but here is not solution

Comment: could you please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: This isn't a real problem related to programming, but rather a feature request for UiPath. If the tags are the same on each profile page, wouldn't you create the scraping workflow once, and only once?

Comment: There is no option in uipath for scrap single match element data.I have see many different solution but not found correct solution.

Comment: Please elaborate. Of course UiPath can get data from any element, such as a div, p or h2. Take this example - I used Tesla's profile to create the page, and then executed the robot for BMW (note that Harald Kruger is returned in the output window): https://imgur.com/a/U1B3MIV

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can scrape any structured data.

https://studio.uipath.com/docs/about-data-scraping

Since the data in owler is structured the only problem that prevents you from using scrape wizard to obtain **information of all companies** is that there is no way to indicate the **Next button** in the web page to navigate to the next items.

So "in my opinion" you sould approach this problem differently. You can try the following:

1. Create a list of companies in an excel file or in an orchestrator queue.
2. Open Browser and login (if necessary)
3. Read data from excel or queue.
4. Iterate through items and for each item
5. Navigate to company page by appending baseURL
   (https://www.owler.com/company) with the name of company read from
   excel row / queue transaction and use navigate to activity (https://activities.uipath.com/docs/navigate-to) to go to that page.
6. Use anchor base activity (https://activities.uipath.com/docs/anchor-base) with a fixed element to get the value that you want. Like using Annual Revenue Label as anchor for getting the value of annual revenue. If you can find a proper anchor point it would give you more accurate result also in case of a style change your process would still work.
7. Write the scraped data to your excel file

If you do not know where to start, take a look at https://github.com/UiPath/ReFrameWork, I think it is an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is not in a standard datatable format the extract datatable wizard will not work here, as you have found out. That said, since the data appears in the same location across different companies a dynamic selector can be used. For example the Founded data field will always be in the location contained by this selector:

-<-html app='chrome.exe' title='*Competitors, Revenue and Employees - Owler Company Profil*' />

-<-webctrl css-selector='body>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>p' isleaf='1' tag='P' parentclass='right-block' idx='1' />

*note I have replaced the < tag with -<- to show the code as Stack interprets html

and as such, the pages can change to the other competitors, but the same selector used in a Get Text activity will yield a result corresponding to the competitor itself.

This would be a lot of work, and as such it's probably good to evaluate whether doing so is worth the development time. If you're just wanting to get familiar with the interface I would recommend a more standard datatable that will work well with the wizard, such as can be found here: https://editor.datatables.net/

This will probably be less exciting since the wizard will perform adequately.